# Can I register my Skylanders without a portal?

Tags: skylanders

I have already registered 2 Skylanders online and had been playing through my PC with no problems. I've logged on after an absence and with 2 new Skylanders that I want to register with the webcodes and I can no longer sign in to register my 2 new characters. I don't want the portal and am feeling forced to buy one and can't see why I need it.  Can someone please tell if the portal is necessary and why it had been changed?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Skylanders website](http://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Skylanders-Universe-FAQ), Skylanders Universe (the online app) is *no longer available*. The minigames that were available within the site [are now accessible without an account](http://www.skylanders.com/onlinegames) and online codes are no longer needed or used for them, and neither a portal.

The online codes are now used exclusively with the mobile (iOS) games: Battlegrounds, Sky Patrol & Lost Islands. These don't require a portal either.

A portal is only required for the console version of the games and is available with the starter packs. There is a portal available for the mobile games but it isn't required to play them.